# How to write tests for model in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing, django-models

I want to write tests for Django Models,

My Model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    body = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
```

I have no idea,
How can I make tests for Django model?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, the idea is that you first need to find out *what* you want to test. Just writing tests for the sake of testing is usually not really the way to go. You can for example test with a timefreeze gun when the entry is constructed that the `created_at` and `modified_at` are set correctly, but usually this is more something that Django itself has to test.

Comment: I want to test my model fields

Answer (score 0):

You don't write tests for models, you are directly calling django codes there and trust me, it's already well tested

you should write tests for your own codes and function, how is the models used? write tests for those codes.

PS: if your models contains custom functions writing test for them is a good idea.